# Cassandra get table count using Java driver 4.6

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-java-driver

I am trying to get the count of the table which has more than 100,000 records. I have done to fetch asyncronously with page size as 10000 and incrementing the atomic number by iterating the resultset row. But it takes a lot of time to fetch the counts.

Without async, I was able to fetch the count of resultset using `getAvailablewithoutfetching()` but not for all the rows. is there any better way to fetch count.

1. DSE - 6.8.9
2. Cql - 3.4.5
3. Cassandra - 4.0.0.681
4. Java driver - 4.6.1

Answer (score 0):

@Gvtha, scanning the entire distributed cluster nodes is not recommended in a NoSQL Distributed database such as Apache Cassandra to find the table count. Instead, we have a rock solid tool to achieve that. It is called [DataStax Bulk Loader (aka DSBulk in short)](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/doc/dsbulk/dsbulkAbout.html). This tool can be used to `load`, `unload` and `count` operations with OSS Cassandra/DataStax Enterprise (DSE)/DataStax AstraDB clusters seamlessly.

In short,

```
./dsbulk count -h <hostname_or_ip_of_c*_node> -k <keyspace_name> -t <table_name>
```

Here are few references to get you started quickly,

- [Counting data in tables](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/doc/dsbulk/dsbulkCountData.html)
- [Technical blog going over the DSBulk count operation](https://www.datastax.com/blog/datastax-bulk-loader-counting)
- [DataStax also open-sourced this tool and you could leverage DSBulk using a programmatic way as well](https://www.datastax.com/blog/open-source-ftw-new-tools-apache-cassandratm)

I hope that helps to get you started.

Comment: Can I use this in java code?

Comment: @Gvtha, absolutely yes! (I am assuming you're asking about the programmatic access method). Do [accept my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it answered your original question.

Comment: I have searched lot but not able to find dsbulk to use in java program.

Comment: @Gvtha, please see the 3rd bullet in the answer's reference section where we've the examples of maven dependencies, etc.,